# Reading multiple inputs from Scanner

Tags: java

(I'm a beginner at Java)
I am trying to write a program that asks for 6 digits from the user using a scanner, then from those 6 individual digits find the second highest number. So far this works however I'd like to have the input read from a single line rather than 6 separate lines. I've heard of delimiters and tokenisation, but have no idea how to implement it. I'ld like to have it read like "Enter 6 digits: 1 2 3 4 5 6" and parsing each digit as a separate variable so i can then place them in an array as shown. If anyone could give me a run-down of how this would work it would be much appreciated. Cheers for your time.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Ask user input 
        System.out.println("Enter 6 digits: ");            
        //New Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Assign 6 variables for each digit
        int num1 = input.nextInt();            
        int num2 = input.nextInt();            
        int num3 = input.nextInt();            
        int num4 = input.nextInt();            
        int num5 = input.nextInt();            
        int num6 = input.nextInt();            

      //unsorted array
      int num[] = {num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6};     
      //Length 
      int n = num.length;     
       //Sort 
      Arrays.sort(num);
       //After sorting
      // Second highest number is at n-2 position

       System.out.println("Second highest Number: "+num[n-2]);

 }           
}
```

Comment: Read in the line as a string, split the string, parse ints from the split string. All of these tasks are extensively detailed online.

Comment: and ..; what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Stultuske how do i obtain separate int variables from a single line from a scanner so i may place them in an array. thanks.

Comment: @utnicho sleepToken already explained the steps to take

Comment: @sleepToken sorry man i just started java a few days ago, so i should just change the variable type to String for my scanner?

Comment: `String str = input.nextLine()`. Now all you need to do is research *how to split a String in java*, *how to iterate through an array*, and *how to convert a String to an int in java* (in that order).

Comment: @sleepToken ok thank you for your help, i'll look into it

Comment: Calling `nextInt` multiple time, as you are already doing, will will read six `int`s, whether those `int`s are each on six separate lines, or all on one line separated by spaces, or anything in between those two extremes.  But if you want to **require** them to be only all on one line, you'll need to use a solution involving `nextLine()` and parsing that line yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your solution does this allready!**

If you go through the documentation of scaner you will find out that your code works with different inputs, as long they are integers separated by whitespace and/or line seperators.

But you can optimice your code, to let it look nicer:

```
public static void main6(String[] args) {
    // Ask user input
    System.out.println("Enter 6 digits: ");
    // New Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Assign 6 variables for each digit
    int size=6;
    int[] num=new int[size];
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        num[i]=input.nextInt();
    }
    Arrays.sort(num);
    // After sorting
    // Second highest number is at n-2 position

    System.out.println("Second highest Number: " + num[size - 2]);
}
```

As an additional hint, i like to mention this code still produces lot of overhead you can avoid this by using:

```
public static void main7(String[] args) {
    // Ask user input
    System.out.println("Enter 6 digits: ");
    // New Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Assign 6 variables for each digit
    int size=6;
    int highest=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int secondhighest=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i=0;i<size-1;i++) {
        int value=input.nextInt();
        if (value>highest) {
            secondhighest=highest;
            highest=value;
        } else if (value>secondhighest) {
            secondhighest=value;
        }
    }
    //give out second highest
    System.out.println("Second highest Number: " + secondhighest);
}
```

if you do not like to point on highest if there are multiple highest, you can replace the else if:

```
public static void main7(String[] args) {
    // Ask user input
    System.out.println("Enter 6 digits: ");
    // New Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Assign 6 variables for each digit
    int size = 6;
    int highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int secondhighest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        int value = input.nextInt();
        if (value > highest) {
            secondhighest = highest;
            highest = value;
        } else if (secondhighest==Integer.MIN_VALUE&&value!=highest) {
            secondhighest=value;
        }
    }
    // give out second highest
    System.out.println("Second highest Number: " + secondhighest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that:

take a single line string, then parse it.

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        ....
        String numString = input.nextLine();
        String[] split = numString.split("\\s+");
        int num[] = new int[split];
        // assuming there will be always atleast 6 numbers.
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            num[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
        }
        ... 
      //Sort 
      Arrays.sort(num);
       //After sorting
      // Second highest number is at n-2 position

       System.out.println("Second highest Number: "+num[n-2]);
```

Comment: your first option isn't valid, since it doesn't meet the OP's requirements of having all the numbers on a single line. Your second limits it to max 6 numbers. use split.length instead of a hardcoded 6

Comment: @ruhul i think i understand what you did, so the new variable obtained from the scanner is numString right? Which is the string of numbers (e.g 1 2 3 4 5 6) however how do i put that into an array and then sort it? i keep getting errors when i try int num[numString]; thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there are many ways to do that. I will give you two ways:
1. Use lambda functions - this way is more advanced but very practical:

```
Integer[] s = Arrays.stream(input.nextLine().split(" ")).map(Integer::parseInt).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

- first create a stream, you can read more about streams here
- than read the whole line "1 2 3 ...."
- split the line by space " " and after this point the stream will look like ["1", "2", "3" ....]
- to convert the strings to int "map" operator is used
- and finally collect the stream into Integer[]

  2. You can use an iterator and loop as many times as you need and read from the console.

     `int num[] = new int[6];
     for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         num[i] = input.nextInt();
     }`